# how to run the preact application using webpack-dev-server

Tags: node.js, webpack, preact

Please teach me the solution how to run the preact application using webpack-dev-server.
I am getting the following errors in "npm run start"

package.json file

[image]

npm run start

[image]

Comment: We do have [Preact CLI](https://github.com/preactjs/preact-cli) which is a Webpack-based build tool and dev server btw.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my error by changing "start:root" and "start:query" as follows.

"start:root": "SET NODE_ENV=development && webpack -p --config webpack.config.root.js --watch",

"start:query": "SET NODE_ENV=development && webpack -p --config webpack.config.query.js --watch",